# Add Reference 4.0 Dll to 4.0 ClientProfile application in VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-client-profile

I am working on Multiple versioned projects. One is **4.0** Version and another is **4.0 ClientProfile.**

```
   How could i add 4.0 Assembly to 4.0 ClientProfile. 

   If i adding like normal reference means its not adding properly or the classes i cannot access it.
```

**Tried Solution:** I changed 4.0 client to 4.5 means its working fine. But My project support only for 4.0 clientProfile.How can i achieve this?

TanQ,
Saars.

Comment: If the assembly has references to types that are not available in the Client Profile then this is not possible.  The program can of course never run on a machine that only has the client profile installed.  You *must* select the full version of .NET as the target framework.  This is not a problem, the Client Profile in 4.0 is nonsensical anyway.  It is only 15% smaller than the full version.

Comment: I added System.Web Reference to the ClientProfile Project now its running good.. Thanks @hans Passant for ur time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i directly changing the project version 4.0 ClientProfile to 4.0 Means the application not running.

But if we Add the Reference of **system.web** means it will automatically converts to 4.0 .

So it supported to 4.0 version assembly reference too. Now Project is running good.